# Typing of using a subclass of a generic class

Tags: python-3.x, generics, mypy

I created a generic class (Baz) which except an instance with a generic interface (Foo),
and manipulates it.

I made a non-generic class (Bar), subclassing the interface with a concrete type (str).

Inside the class the types work, but when I use the non-generic class with the manipulator class, I have type errors.

I expected mypy to infer the concretization of the generic type from the usage.

What do I do wrong, how to correctly type this scenario?

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


T = TypeVar("T")


class Foo(Generic[T]):
    def foo(self, arg: T) -> None:
        pass


class Bar(Foo[str]):
    def foo(self, arg: str) -> None:
        print(arg + " boldly runs")


T1 = TypeVar("T1")


class Baz(Generic[T1]):
    def sirRobin(self, instance: Foo[T1], param: T1) -> None:
        instance.foo(param)


# no problem, no output
Baz[str]().sirRobin(Foo(), "she")
Baz[int]().sirRobin(Foo(), 1)
print("----")
# Argument 1 to "sirRobin" of "Baz" has incompatible type "Bar"; expected "Foo[<nothing>]"  [arg-type]
# Argument 2 to "sirRobin" of "Baz" has incompatible type "str"; expected < nothing > [arg-type]
# works as expected though
Baz().sirRobin(Bar(), "he")
```

output:

```
----
he boldly runs
```

Comment: Well, this might have been inferred properly (your typing is, strictly speaking, correct), but `mypy` fails to do so. Do you really need `Baz` to be generic class? From what you show,  seems like `Generic[T1]` base can be simply removed, so that only `sirRobin` method remains generic, and `mypy` is happy with that.

Comment: For the original application I need a generic type. Thank you for confirming that my typing is correct. I am issuing a bug report now.

Comment: This is not a real bug, just an inference limitation. The generics are sometimes postponed for later inference in mypy, but it's used only in most common cases. You probably want to add `__init__` with that type var bound, so that inference doesn't need to be delayed.

Comment: For a static typechecker an inference limitation is a bug, especially when there is no workaround, as the whole point of the thing is to check the code and provide information for the tooling in IDE. The most valuable information for that tooling is the inferred types.

Comment: If you're looking for more powerful inference, consider using other typecheckers - e.g. pyright handles such things much better (and your code passes it without modifications). `mypy` does less inference in favour of being explicit about expected types.